# Can switch statement in Java take "view" as argument?

Tags: java, android, switch-statement

I want switch statement to take View as argument. I know view is basically widget on layout. But it doesn't work when I put view as argument. It show error at case green as "constant expression required"

```
public void onClick(View v) {
   switch(v) {
      case green:
          CL.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00ff00"));
          break;
      case R.id.button:
          CL.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
          break;
   }
}
```

It works fine when I take switch(v.getId()) as parameter:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()) {
            case R.id.button2:
                CL.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00ff00"));
                break;
            case R.id.button:
                CL.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                break;
        }
 }
```

Is there way to to take view as parameter? I have already assigned view in earlier code

```
Button blue= (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
Button green=findViewById(R.id.button2);
```

Comment: I think you cannot pass object in switch as switch uses `==` for comparison and object could not be compared using `==`. Intead you can pass some value of object to be compared like `obj.val`.

Comment: No, you can't do this.  But `switch` will work with integers or strings, so if you can find a way to switch on either of these, it should work.

Comment: Learn more about what is possible with the `switch` statement in the [Oracle Java Trails](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) (*A switch works with the byte, short, char, and int primitive data types. It also works with enumerated types (discussed in Enum Types), the String class, and a few special classes that wrap certain primitive types: Character, Byte, Short, and Integer (discussed in Numbers and Strings).*)

Comment: @user8190410 It won't even _compile_ if an object is passed to `switch`, AFAIK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable in a `switch` cannot be anything but a primitive, a wrapper thereof, an enum, or a String.

As per the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.11):

> The type of the Expression must be char, byte, short, int, Character, Byte, Short, Integer, String, or an enum type (§8.9), or a compile-time error occurs.

As for your question:

> IS there way to to take view as parameter?

No, not as such. You might however create an `Enum` type for every view that should be switched on. Normally, you might extend the `View` class or simply give it an enum field. However, since it seems to be a library object you have no control over, I would map the view IDs to to enum values, as such:

```
    switch(v.getId()) {
        case Foo.BAR1:
            // doStuff
            break;
        case Foo.BAR2:
           // doOtherStuff
           break;
        default:
    }
```

Note that in this case and every other where you use an `Enum`, the value of the enum must be set at compile time.

Comment: thanks for clarification but i dnt see you using enum in switch statement, switch(v.getId()) is still a string paramenter not enum? correct me if i am wrong

Comment: What do you mean? The `switch` contains the value of the input parameter (which is variable), you don't switch on the enum value itself (which is constant) - you match it against the variable parameter value.

Comment: Would the downvoters care to explain their reasoning?

Comment: thanks now i got it... and the guy who down voted your comment must be some low life... btw thanks for your answer it cleared my doubts.